# Telegram ReplyKeyboardMarkup with ForceReply at same time

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

how to make message with 2 keyboard Reply Keyboard Markup And Force Reply at same time like Poll Bot in group but i want to this format be in private not in group
is there any solution for this problem?
i use java-telegram-bot-api
thanks alot

Comment: There is no bots with 2 different keyboards at same time. Or you can provide screenshot? Pollbot show one keyboard for asking questions and another for answering.

Comment: my intention was force reply with keyboard at same time
when people want answer to poll question 
1- force reply answer
2-Reply Keyboard Markup

Comment: @pengrad do you update your api to Bot Platform 2.0????????

Comment: Yes, on next weekend